# Authenticate Windows 10 User to Continue in C++

Tags: c++, windows, passwords

I am writing a Windows 10 application in c++ that will have the option to display sensitive information on the screen. If the user clicks the display button I would like to have them enter a password to continue. Rather than writing my own password management system, I was hoping to simply to have the user enter their windows password and have windows authenticate them. This would allow people to use my computer and the base program functionality without me worrying about them clicking the display button while my back was turned.

Is there a windows SDK call that would allow me to request windows to force the user to enter their password (or even enter administrator mode) to continue?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if(userAuthenticates())
{
    displayInfo();
}
else
{
    displayError(FAILED_AUTH);
}
```

but I don't know how to cause windows to authenticate for me in `userAuthenticates()`.

Comment: If the user is running your program, they are already authenticated in Windows. If in fact that is a different person because the original user walked away without pressing Win+L, that is not something you should be trying to fix.

Comment: @GSerg I would like to follow the pattern used in such things as the Chrome and Firefox password manager where to view stored passwords you may enter a master password. This adds an extra level of security such that operator is protected from casual users of the system and accidentally displaying the information. Because I would not be implementing a unique password this would equate to forcing the user to indicate he is the legitimate user of the system and that he explicitly intends to display the information at this time.

Comment: Then it's probably [Asking the User for Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717794(v=vs.85).aspx) you want.